# Object Randomly Going Transparent When Rendered

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, transparency, shadowcatcher

I have an animation that I did with a tree falling over. It's going to be put over some footage I have so I'm just rendering the object and the animation itself. I added transparency to the background and am rendering it out with a shadow catcher and transparent background fine.

The problem I have is that every 10 frames or so the top part of the tree, the part that's being animated, just randomly goes transparent for no reason.

There are no keyframes at those frames to turn off the layer or anything like that. It just for seemingly no reason disappears and then reappears a frame or 2 later.

Edit (More info and download link added):

Here is a link to the blend file
https://we.tl/t-bnLkoReFz9

For example here is the tree at frame 6 in the animation:
[image]

And here is the tree at frame 7 in the animation:
[image]

When you watch the video as a whole it just looks like it's stuttering between visible and invisible. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjYkSg0Ze8E

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Any chance you are using a Cell Fracture add-on to make this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: without having seen any of your settings how should we know!? can be tons of reasons...so pls provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: I added the blend file and some screenshots of the render to show as an example

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening here, but when Noise texture node is plugged to Roughness, Blender crashes in Material Viewport View (=Eevee) mode. So try to exclude this node from node-tree (or mute) and try render in Cycles to see if make it difference. ... also your Mix-ing Texture Coordinates is not clear to me so it can be an issue for Curve object (Tree trunk).